# Is it good to mention in a recommendation letter that a student always attends office hours? What kind of impression does this make?

Tags: graduate-admissions, teaching, recommendation-letter, office-hours

I'm writing a letter of recommendation for a student in my class who always came to my office hours.  Is it good to say he attended a lot of office hours?  Will this make the admissions committee think he is a diligent student, or too dependent on the instructors?  He is applying for a master's program in computer science.

Comment: You can talk about why he comes, and what kind of discussions you have with him.

Comment: The usual question in the site is "what can I write about a student I nearly don't know", but you know this student, so you are in better position than the average professor to write a letter of recommendation.

Comment: Voted to close due to lack of clarity, as explained in answer by @DSVA.  If you edit the answer and want a reopen vote, please address a comment to me.

Comment: My immediate question is "But what did they **do** during office hours?"  Did they ask lots of insightful questions?  Did they give insightful answers to other students' questions?  Did they frequently ask for clarifications on elementary/prerequisite material?  Did they bring you candy and beg for extra points?  Did they silently take a picture of the whiteboard every five minutes?  Did they just sit quietly in the corner?

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could really put that like you want to. Attending all office hours could mean a lot of things like the student is extremly insecure and needs confirmation on everything (even though he might be able to do it on his own) or he's not afraid to admit he doesn't know something and asks before doing something wrong.

It really depends on what you think of the student and if you think he is good enough. From your post we really don't know if attending the office hours was a positive or negative thing. But I wouldn't really write about the office hours themself but more general about the action of the student.